# node js get image url

Tags: node.js, multer

i want to
1-choose an image from my filesystem and upload it to server/local
2- get its url back using node js service . i managed to do step 1 and now i want to get the image url instead of getting the success message in res.end
here is my code

```
app.post("/api/Upload", function(req, res) {
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.end("Something went wrong!");
    }
    return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
});
});
```

i'm using multer to upload the image.

Comment: i did it using `return res.send(req.file.path);` in my post method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this, using `AWS S3` and it returns the url of the image uploaded

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: <AWS_ACCESS_KEY>,
  secretAccessKey: <AWS_SECRET>
})

const uploadImage = file => {
  const replaceFile = file.data_uri.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')
  const buf = new Buffer(replaceFile, 'base64')

  const s3 = new AWS.S3()
  s3.upload({
    Bucket: <YOUR_BUCKET>,
    Key: <NAME_TO_SAVE>,
    Body: buf,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    return data.Location; // this is the URL
  })
}
```

also you can check this express generator, which has the route to upload images to `AWS S3` https://www.npmjs.com/package/speedbe

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are saving the image on the server file system and not a Storage solution like AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage, where you get the url after upload.

Since, you are storing it on the filesystem, you can rename the file with a unique identifier like uuid or something else.

Then you can make a GET route and request that ID in query or path parameter and then read the file having that ID as the name and send it back.